# Calculate Case Resolve Time Based on Business hours

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I need a solution to calculate the hour of resolving a case.
Its important to be in my local business hours.
My mostly cases resolve via workflows.
What are the possible ways and solutions?
Can I create a service activity when case is created and update in on resolve time?
If yes Could anybody explain a little more about this?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

We can not access calendarrule entity which describe rules of calendar we have.
There is a unsupported way to create a query and call that query on your plugin/workflow.